# What is the purpose of naming a function that is a value of a property in an object?

Tags: javascript, syntax

```
var timers = {                                                  //#1

    timerID: 0,                                                   //#2
    timers: [],                                                   //#2

    add: function(fn) {                                           //#3
        this.timers.push(fn);
    },

    start: function runNext() {                                   //#4
        if (this.timerID) return;
        (function() {
            if (timers.timers.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < timers.timers.length; i++) {
                    if (timers.timers[i]() === false) {
                        timers.timers.splice(i,1);
                        i--;
                    }
                }
                timers.timerID = setTimeout(runNext, 0);
            }
        })();
    },
```

The code above is from *Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja* by John Resig. the part I don't understand is where he assigns a function to the property of `start` and then names that function `runNext`. Can someone please offer some clarification?

Comment: As far as I know, it's usually for debugging, especially to avoid anonymous functions in stack traces during errors.

Comment: In order for a function to call itself, it needs a name.  The `setTimeout(runNext, 0)` call refers to the function, which it can't do if the function is completely anonymous.

Comment: It's also being called again in `setTimeout`, maybe resolving the local function name is faster than resolving `timers.start` as well?

Comment: @Eric Jablow: how about `this.start`?

Comment: @Mike Christensen: that doesn't sound correct

Comment: Guys, how about creating a semantic context: function is started with `start` and further iterations are called `runNext`?

Comment: When we are inside the anonymous method and call setTimeout, "this" refers to the window object, so we cannot call this.start. We may change to call timers.start, but that would create a tightly coupled code. I think that's the reason he gives it a name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "name" of a function also serves a special role which is particularly useful when used in a [FunctionExpression](http://es5.github.io/#x13)<sup>1</sup>:

```
x = function theFunc (z) {
    // theFunc is in scope here, and so can be used to refer
    // to the function itself in a recursive manner
    //   (in the posted code it is used with setTimeout)
    return z > 0 ? theFunc(z - 1) * z : 1;
};
// theFunc is NOT in scope here in valid ECMAScript; IE quirks anyone?
```

Unlike `x`, `theFunc` above will *always* refer to the particular function-object. Without this name an additional closure (or use of `this` plumbing) would be required to access the function recursively. Also, the tight binding makes `theFunc` independent of the current `this` binding, which may be good or bad - note that after the call to `setTimeout`, `theFunc` will be called in a *different* binding context (which also makes the use of `this.timerID` suspect).

In ECMAScript 3rd edition, then function name (Identifier) and arguments.callee would evaluate to the same function-object inside the scope. However, arguments.callee is invalid per ECMAScript 5th edition "strict" mode.

The name may also show up in stack-traces, `toString()` and `name`/`displayName` (as implemented).

---

<sup>1</sup>From [ES5 Annotated, Function Declarations](http://es5.github.io/#x13):

> The Identifier in a FunctionExpression can be referenced from inside the FunctionExpression's FunctionBody to allow the function to call itself recursively ..

Comment: "so can be used to refer to the function itself in a recursive manner" --- he could call it as `this.start()`

Comment: @zerkms Good call. I added a bit about that.

Answer (score -1):

In JavaScript, everything is an object with members, and those members can serve as properties or methods according to what you put in them.

In this case, `timer` will have some members that will be used as methods (`add` and `start`). In order to do that, they will contain references to `function` code. The only reason he gives a name to the code reference in `start` (`runNext`), is so he can recursively call that function again from inside. The second function reference you see inside `runNext`, is another anonymous function reference that is not even being assigned to anything, but it's just there to make it return something at that moment for `runNext`.

Comment: He could run it recursively with `this.next`. Why to follow such a tricky declaration then?

Comment: Because Javascript programmers love hackiness. Yes, he could put that in another method and call it via `this`. He also could take that anonymous function inside out of there.

Comment: "Yes, he could put that in another method" --- you don't need another method, you can call it from itself: http://jsfiddle.net/rnaqT/

Comment: @zerkms `this` is undefined within the iife. And if it weren't, it would become undefined when the function were called by setTimeout the first time, so it wouldn't recurse any longer.

Comment: @zerkms Why hardcode the path in the object to the function to recursively call when you can easily just refer to the function name? While the OP's code is a simple example, it could get annoying to use the exact path when you just want to recurse: http://jsfiddle.net/rnaqT/1/

Comment: @zerkms Why wouldn't you be consistent and use the same conventions in all of your code? If you need to recursively call a function in an object, use the same code consistently, no matter how simple or complex the object. Why are you calling it tricky? I don't see how it's **bad**

Comment: @Ian: I'm calling it tricky because it's uncommon, so that people guessing instead of giving a simple answer ;-)

Comment: @zerkms re: "In JavaScript, everything is an object with members" - while that's true, JavaScript has autoboxing

Comment: @zerkms It may not be common, but it's clearly useful for recursive calling.

Comment: @zerkms Right, but I guess I was referring more to like `"asdf".indexOf("s")`, but that's different than what you're saying and not relevant like what you're saying. I agree that statement isn't worded properly/correctly, especially for what the point is.

Comment: @zerkms: Primitives are objects too, even if you can not give them arbitrary properties. Try this instead: `console.log((5).toString())` - Object with `toString` method.

Comment: @zerkms: what are you talking about? The parenthesis are there just to avoid a syntax error. You first wanted to prove this using a variable. Using your same exact proof case, its still an object: `a = 5; console.log(a.toString());`. Numbers have methods, that makes them objects too.

Comment: @zerkms: Yeah, ok. They don't have methods. Except methods can be called on them because of how JS internals work. So, without doing anything else, you can call methods on primitives. So, you criticizing my statement "Everything in Javascript is an object" is right, because I should've said something really different like "Everything in Javascript can be used as an object". Right? By the way, in your example, there's no way to compare `a` against `a_tmp` as a different object/value. `Number()` returns a number, not a different object. They are identical. And you can call methods on both.